# C#: Different syntax forms when firing event

Tags: c#, events

I found different syntax version of firing an event in c#, and I cant really figure out what exactly the difference is between:

```
if (OnMyEvent!= null)
    OnMyEvent(this, new MyEventEventArgs());
```

and:

```
OnMyEvent.Invoke(this, new MyEventEventArgs());
```

especially if I dont have any thread context changes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Reflector or ildasm, you can see that these compile (modulo the `null` check) into the exact same thing (a call to `Invoke()`).

As for what's desirable, you should always check for `null` and you'll more often see the invocation syntax over the `Invoke()` syntax.

Comment: Thank you! [filling to >15 chars in this comment :)]

Answer (score 1):

The Invoke method would be useful when attempting to trigger the event by reflection.